# How do i remove array item from collection

Tags: mongodb

How do i remove array item from collection in mongodb? Below is my structure.

```
{
    "__v" : 12,
    "_id" : ObjectId("52cc27daasdsc797ec7s8000001"),
    "email" : "email@email.com",
    "joindate" : ISODate("2014-01-07T16:14:18.158Z"),
    "location" : "Canada",
    "name" : "Albert",
    "oauthID" : 58558855,
    "myvideos" : [
            {
                    "vid" : "wssEoGquzsiw1c",
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-06-01T05:28:32.713Z")
            },
            {
                    "vid" : "0_Vko7RXsdsmoI",
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-06-01T05:29:01.888Z")
            },
            {
                    "vid" : "ctbvhucsds050g",
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-06-01T05:29:27.395Z")
            }
    ],
    "username" : "myusername"
}
```

I would like to remove item vid (ctbvhucsds050g) from the myvideos array.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to this.

```
db.users.update({"name":"Albert"}, {'$pull': {"myvideos": {"vid": "ctbvhucsds050g" }}});
```